# Compare two objects while filtering out specific keys

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to figure out the best way to do this. Let's say I have two Objects

```
const baseObject = {
   firstName: "John",
   lastName: "Doe",
   dob: "01/01/00",
   siblings: []
}

const updatedObject = {
   firstName: "Johnathan",
   lastName: "Doe",
   dob: "01/01/00",
   siblings: []
}
```

I want to compare my `baseObject` with my `updatedObject` while omitting `dob & siblings` to find any differences and the changes in another obj.

I have been struggling just how to do this. I have played with .filter, .map etc. with no ground being made.

Note: Yes the [] does actually matter.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1. That's not valid JS. 2. Post the code you've tried so far 3. how about `if (a.firstName == b.firstName && a.lastName == b.lastName)`?

Comment: @ChrisG I would prefer to not compare each object key value individually because eventually, I would expect my objects to grow.

Comment: My first thought without a workstation would be to create a function taking in params: base and updated (or just updated). Then iterate over the keys and use filter on the keys to check if values have changed. Does that make sense? Otherwise I rely on 2 way data binding toolkits/frameworks such as KnockoutJS/React/VueJS to observe changes dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to compare two objects on limited keys, either you need to specifically mention each key in if condition or you need to maintain separate memory for those keys. If you have less `excluding` keys then maintain an array for that else for `including` keys.

```
const baseObject = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  dob: "01/01/00",
  siblings: []
}

const updatedObject = {
  firstName: "Johnathan",
  lastName: "Doe",
  dob: "01/01/00",
  siblings: []
}

// Excluding
function compareWithoutKeys(first = {}, second = {}, excludes = []) {
  return Object.entries(first).every(([key, value]) =>
    excludes.includes(key) ? true : second[key] === value
  )
}
compareWithoutKeys(baseObject, updatedObject, ['dob', 'siblings']) // true/false

// Including
function compareWithKeys(first = {}, second = {}, includes = []) {
  return Object.entries(first).every(([key, value]) =>
    includes.includes(key) ? second[key] === value : true
  )
}
compareWithKeys(baseObject, updatedObject, ['firstName', 'lastName']) // true/false
```

### Update for comparing more than just strings.

In case you want to compare more than string maybe like `siblings`(which is an array) you have to update the comparison function, you will check the type of value and then compare it accordingly. Like if the value is an `Object` then compare every key or if the value is `Array` then compare every index. Something like:

```
function isEqual(first, second) {
  const firstType = Object.prototype.toString.call(first)
  const secondType = Object.prototype.toString.call(second)

  if (firstType !=== secondType) {
    return false
  }

  switch (expression) {
    case '[object Array]': return first.every((value, index) => value === second[index])
    case '[object Object]': return Object.entries(first).every((value, index) => value === second[index])
    default: return first === second
  }
}

// Excluding
function compareWithoutKeys(first = {}, second = {}, excludes = []) {
  return Object.entries(first).every(([key, value]) =>
    excludes.includes(key) ? true : isEqual(value, second[key])
  )
}
// usage
compareWithoutKeys(baseObject, updatedObject, ['dob', 'siblings']) // true/false
compareWithoutKeys(baseObject, updatedObject, ['dob']) // true/false

// Including
function compareWithKeys(first = {}, second = {}, includes = []) {
  return Object.entries(first).every(([key, value]) =>
    includes.includes(key) ? isEqual(value, second[key]) : true
  )
}
// usage
compareWithKeys(baseObject, updatedObject, ['firstName', 'lastName']) // true/false
compareWithKeys(baseObject, updatedObject, ['firstName', 'lastName', 'siblings']) // true/false
```

**Note:** This will only do first level of comparison, if you want to do deep levels comparison like maybe `array of objects on which every key is an array`, either you have to use a **recursive function** or fallback to libraries like **lodash**.

A recursive could be something like following, but I haven't tested the below code.

```
function isEqual(first, second) {
  const firstType = Object.prototype.toString.call(first)
  const secondType = Object.prototype.toString.call(second)

  if (firstType !=== secondType) {
    return false
  }

  switch (expression) {
    case '[object Array]': return first.every((value, index) => isEqual(second[index], value))
    case '[object Object]': return Object.entries(first).every((value, index) => isEqual(second[index], value))
    default: return first === second
  }
}
```

**Article on recursive comaprison:** https://gomakethings.com/check-if-two-arrays-or-objects-are-equal-with-javascript/

**Lodash's isEqual:** https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isEqual

Comment: Is there a way to actually include `siblings`? If I dont exclude it the function will always return false but there are some cases where I will want to check to see if siblings are the same or not.

Comment: @Ardz you may want to see my answer for that, maybe

Answer (score 1):

> I would prefer to not compare each object key value individually
>   because eventually, I would expect my objects to grow

Finding diffs in javascript objects is not so easy if you think so. There is no magic function (I have searched this a lot) that can do it for you. That's why you have to iterate through the keys and make everything manually.

Example:

```
const changes = Object.keys(baseObject)
.filter(key => !['dob', 'siblings'].includes(key))
.map(key => (
  {
    property: key, 
    oldVal: baseObject[key], 
    newVal: updatedObject[key],
    wasUpdated: baseObject[key] === updatedObject[key]
  }
 ))
```

P.S. You did not provide what result should look like, so I wrote the code without knowing it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a flat object and you don't want to compare arrays inside (where sequence will matter) You can `stringify` them ignoring the keys you don't want and compare the strings.

```js
const baseObject = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    dob: "01/01/00",
    siblings: []
  },
  updatedObject1 = {
    firstName: "Johnathan",
    lastName: "Doe",
    dob: "01/01/00",
    siblings: []
  },
  updatedObject2 = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    dob: "01/02/00",
    siblings: [10, 20]
  },
  keysToIgnore = ["dob", "siblings"],
  toJson = o => JSON.stringify(o, (k, v) => {
    if (!keysToIgnore.includes(k)) { return v }
  }),
  compare = (o1, o2) => toJson(o1)===toJson(o2);
  
  console.log('baseObject, updatedObject1: ' + compare(baseObject, updatedObject1));
  console.log('baseObject, updatedObject2: ' +compare(baseObject, updatedObject2));
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is a very expensive operation which should be avoided, and only used in case of last option left.

Comment: Well, this just another way of doing it, since the approaches with recursion or check each key separately is already added. sometime we need a cleaned approach as well, when performance is impacting or became a factor. more on any solution should be a combination of readability/cleaner approach and obviously performance.